# Android Push Notification unauthorized error 401

Tags: php, android, push-notification

I have created an Android app with Googles' OAuth 2.0 (from developer console) and has an API key for Android application (it use Google Maps, which works by the way).

However, my problem is that I'm using Push Notifications and it works on the android application though (I get the registration ID), but on the server it doesn't work at all.

I'm using PHP and the problem seems to be the API key which is the same as the one I've for the Android application.

So what key am I supposed to use? And how do I retrieve it?

Code:

```
<?php

function send_push_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {


        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=An_Api_Key',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        //print_r($headers);
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
    }?>
```

Comment: The code above is extracted from that code, this is used as proof of concept so I don't need the database code. So there is nothng wrong with the code, only the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check allowed IP addresses in your Google API. You can restrict API access to certain IP addresses and by default one IP address is set when you create new API project.

Remove that IP address so that any IP address (Including your local machine's server) can connect and access the API.

I have implemented similar kind of code and got 401 error. Above fix worked for me.  Hope that helps you as well.

Comment: And how do I do that in the Googles new Developers Console?

Comment: I think you should go back to old developers console and edit it. For new console, I need to check.

Comment: I went back to the old and added domains to the list at the bottom. But it still doesn't work. The php page is placed on a subdomain, could that be the problem?

Comment: I don't think subdomain may cause the problem. First try removing all allowed IP addresses so that API can be called from any hosted server or local server. Go to your API project -> Credentials. Click on `Edit allowed IPs` and remove all IPs specified. Try your application. If this works, there is some problem with IP which you are providing for your domain. Otherwise there can be error in API key or so. However first do try this.

Comment: The problem is that I can't find Edit allowed IPS under Credentials.
The only sections I have is:
- Compute Engine and App Engine
- Client ID for Android application
- Key for Android application

Non of them has the button or link as you mentioned. The only place I ad IPs is in the browser key section and the Notification endpoints page.

Comment: Solved it, i missed a button to create server key. Thanks for your help.