# Gettint 401 Error in Server Side gcm PHP Script

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting the following error when i am hitting send notification in my gcm server side php script.

```
 Unauthorized
 Error 401
```

I added my server IP to the project goolge console allowed ip list.

What else i am missing? Any Idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868314/android-push-notification-unauthorized-error-401

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade got ans on the link. thanks. this was very useful

Comment: @sohel12_cse_ju glad to help you.